# Record is only update from API

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, apexrest, httppost

The record which came from Rest API should only update from API, no user can update the record manually.

```
for(Opportunity guestuser: trigger.new)
{
    id currentuser = guestuser.CreatedById;
                User thisUser = [select Id FROM User where Id =:guestuser.CreatedById];

    id userid=UserInfo.getUserId(); 
    system.debug('currentuser'+currentuser);
    if(currentuser != userid)
    {
        guestuser.addError('You cannot Update this Application.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion, please be careful with the naming of your variables and choosing variable types. The currentUser variable doesn't contain the current user id which is confusing for anyone that reads it. Your also placing the Ids in the variable type String while the variable type Id would be correct. Are you using a Salesforce Site Guest User for this integration or a dedicated API user?

Comment: I am hitting the API with Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to check if the user that is editing the record is:

1. The API user and that user has created this opportunity (I think?)
2. The user is not the API user and the opportunity was created by the API user

   ```
   Id apiUserId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'API User'].Id;
   Id currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId(); 

   for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
     if( (currentUserId == apiUserId && opp.CreatedById != apiUserId) ||
         (currentUserId != apiUserId && opp.CreatedById == apiUserId))
     {
        opp.addError('This opportunity can\'t be edited by you.')
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: yes, you are right but how I find the 'API user'  name

Comment: When you create a user you have to give the user a name.  I don't know what you named your user. If you don't know either you could try querying recently created users to find out.  For instance [SELECT Id, Name FROM USER WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK].

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches to solve this - Assuming you have a dedicated integration user that the REST API uses.

1. Using Sharing Rules: Set the OWD of your object to Private, and create a Sharing Rule that shares all the records created/owned by the Integration user with everyone with **ReadOnly** Access. While records created/owned by everyone other than the Integration user are shared with **ReadWrite** access.
2. Use a trigger: During before or after update, check if the CreatedById's user is your integration user. If yes, check if the current user (`UserInfo.getUserId()`) is the same one. If not, [throw an exception](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm).

Comment: The Above solution is not solving my problem. I am able to update record manually.

Comment: If you went with the Sharing Rules approach, then ensure the profile of the user doesn't have Read All/Modify All permission on the object - Typically if you are a system admin, then you can see and edit all data.